# Functional Javascript Database but in a Class

Tags: typescript

```
"use strict";

import { Pool, Client } from "pg";

const pool = new Pool();

let config = {
  database: process.env.DATABASE,
  host: process.env.HOST,
  port: Number(process.env.PORT),
  user: process.env.USERNAME,
  password: process.env.SECRET
};

function connect() {
  pool.connect(this.config);
}

export { pool };
```

This is normally how I would connect to the DB, not even sure if it works though. But I need to make it be wrapped with a Class named Postgresql

```
const async = require("async");

class Postgresql {
  constructor(
    database: string,
    host: string,
    port: number,
    user: string,
    password: string
  ) {}

  // Create a PostgreSQL DB instance
  connect() {
    let pool = new Pool({
      database: process.env.DATABASE,
      host: process.env.HOST,
      port: Number(process.env.PORT),
      user: process.env.USERNAME,
      password: process.env.SECRET
    });
  }
}

export { Postgresql };
```

I will be accessing this model from a database.service.ts file, and calling the connect() method from there.

```
import { Postgresql } from "../models/common/database/index";
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

const databaseService: {
  // Not sure if this is the proper way to create reusable GET service
  // GET method requires config(object of ENV VAR) and returns a Promise of type string/json/obj (?)
  get: (config: object) => Promise<string | JSON | object>;
} = {
  get: (config: object) =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // If the Postgresql.connect is false return error, not sure if when the connection fails if it even returns false
      if (!Postgresql.connect) reject(new Error(`Can not connect to Postgres`));
      Postgresql.connect(function(err, client, done) {
        // Hardcoded query, not sure how to make dynamic
        let query = "SELECT * FROM products";

        // Is the client part of the pool
        client.query(query, function(err, result) {
          done();
          console.log(result);
        });
      });
    })
};
```

In my databaseService class, it says that Postgresql does not contain a property connect though, I think I understand that it is a method. But whenever I try to create a property in the class, it won't let me, "A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected."

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do, but since you've created a `Postgresql` class, you need to instantiate an instance of it before you can use it (via `new Postgresql()`). I don't really understand why your constructor takes all of those arguments though, since you don't actually use the values.

Comment: In the end, I want to be able to make a query to my DB using the service

Comment: Why are you doing this?